# MySQL: Select several rows based on several keys from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, key-value

I have these two tables - `user_schedules` and `user_schedule_meta`, shown below:

```
------------------------------------
| id | scheduler_id | status | 
------------------------------------
  1        3          pending 
  2        5          active
  3        6          active
```

and

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | user_schedule_id | meta_key |meta_value
----------------------------------------------
 1         3              course-id    135
 2         3              session-id   15
 3         3              schedule-id  120
```

I want to write a query to enable me select, for example, from both tables where EVERYONE of the below 5 conditions are met:

1. user_schedule_id = 3
2. scheduler_id     = 6
3. session_id      = 15
4. course-id        = 135
5. schedule-id      = 120

This is what I have so far, but it is not working:

```
SELECT user_schedule_meta.`id` FROM user_schedule_meta, user_schedules 
WHERE user_schedules.`scheduler_id` = 6 
AND user_schedules.id = user_schedule_meta.`user_schedule_id` 
AND ( 
(user_schedule_meta.`meta_key` = 'course-id' AND user_schedule_meta.`meta_value` = 135) 
OR (user_schedule_meta.`meta_key` = 'session-id' AND user_schedule_meta.`meta_value` = 15) 
OR (user_schedule_meta.`meta_key` = 'daily-schedule-id' AND user_schedule_meta.`meta_value` = 120) 
) 
GROUP BY user_schedule_meta.`id`
```

Any suggestions what I am not doing right?

Comment: Is there any relation between these 2 tables.

Comment: @Suchit, the `user_schedule_meta` table holds additional information about each entry in the `user_schedules table`

Comment: if you are joining on `user_schedules.id = user_schedule_meta.user_schedule_id` and your condition is `user_schedule_id = 3 and 
scheduler_id = 6` . you will not get any record because they are same column in different table you need to use `or` here.

Comment: do not use `user_schedule_meta, user_schedules` it is an old style writing. use join instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical key-value store lookup problem. These are trickier than they look in SQL, in that they require multiple JOIN operations.

You need a virtual table with one row per `user_schedules.id` value, then you can filter it. So

```
SELECT u.id, u.scheduler_id
  FROM user_schedules u
  JOIN user_schedule_meta a ON u.id=a.user_schedule_id AND a.meta_key='course-id'
  JOIN user_schedule_meta b ON u.id=b.user_schedule_id AND b.meta_key='session-id'
  JOIN user_schedule_meta c ON u.id=c.user_schedule_id AND c.meta_key='daily-schedule-id'

WHERE a.meta_value = 135  -- value associated with course-id
  AND b.meta_value=15     -- value associated with session-id
  AND c.meta_value=120    -- value associated with daily-schedule-id
```

Notice also that you can list your table with associated attributes like this. This trick of joining the key/value table multiple times is a kind of *pivot* operation. I use LEFT JOIN because it will allow the result set to show rows where an attribute is missing.

```
SELECT u.id, u.scheduler_id, u.status,
       a.meta_value AS course_id,
       b.meta_value AS session_id,
       c.meta_value AS daily_schedule_id
  FROM user_schedules u
  LEFT JOIN user_schedule_meta a ON u.id=a.user_schedule_id AND a.meta_key='course-id'
  LEFT JOIN user_schedule_meta b ON u.id=b.user_schedule_id AND b.meta_key='session-id'
  LEFT JOIN user_schedule_meta c ON u.id=c.user_schedule_id AND c.meta_key='daily-schedule-id'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this is code

```
select * from user_schedule_meta where user_schedule_id=3 and 
(meta_key='session-id' AND meta_value=15
or meta_key='daily-schedule-id' AND meta_value=120
or meta_key='course-id' AND meta_value=135
)
```